# Can't clear ListBox selection using SelectedItem = null - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, selecteditem, selectedvalue

I have the following data template (and a corresponding view model, not shown):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type logic:SnapshotListViewModel}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Snapshots}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

ItemsSource is bound to a list of Snapshots, found inside the viewmodel.  My goal is to clear the SelectedItem, so the listbox goes back to its initial, unselected state.  The view model implements IPropertyNotified.

I added a binding in the XAML like so:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem={Binding SelectedSnapshot} .... />
```

In the view model, I set SelectedSnapshot = null, but nothing happens, even though RaisePropertyChanged was called on the property.

I tried again with SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem.  Still no luck.

I finally found the solution, which I will detail below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Forget SelectedItem and SelectedIndex. The answer is **SelectedValue**, along with **IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem**="True".

```
<ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSnapshotValue}" .../>
```

Then, when I call ResetSelection() in the view model, SelectedSnapshotValue is set to null,

```
void ResetSelection()
{
    SelectedSnapshotValue = null;
}
```

which updates the binding in the data template, using the bound property:

```
    private SnapshotViewModel selectedSnapshotValue;
    public SnapshotViewModel SelectedSnapshotValue
    {
        get { return selectedSnapshotValue; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedSnapshotValue != value)
            {
                selectedSnapshotValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSnapshotValue");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the only way I was able to get my listbox to reset the selection.