# Start ListView with no items selected

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

When my app starts, there is a `ListView` populated with data.  How do I set it so that the first row is not selected automatically?  Ie I don't want any items to be selected until the user clicks one

I have tried:

- setting the property bound to the `ListView`'s `SelectedItem` to null (the property is bound two-way),
- setting the `FallBackValue` of the `SelectedItem` to null

but neither of these worked.  Is there a way to do this, or am i stuck with the first item being selected when the app starts?

Comment: Have you tried SelectedIndex = -1

Comment: By default nothing will be selected. Can you show XAML to see whats wrong? Do you use grouping?

Comment: OK, got it sorted. 'IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem' is not your friend.   ;-)

Comment: Yes here is example of IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem =true [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429392/cant-clear-listbox-selection-using-selecteditem-null-mvvm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont put SelectedItem or SelectedIndex it is not selecting anithing, but you want to set than try this code:

```
<ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListViewItem>Some text1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Some text1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Some text1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Some text1</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: It seems you are right about it not selecting anything.  I had 'IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"' which looks like it was causing the problem.  When I removed that, it works.